# Ubuntu directory permissions to share

Tags: bash, permissions, ext4

Assume we have a path `/path/to/usera/data`, its owner is `user_a` and Now we want to share this dir to `user_b` with following steps:

1. add a group `datashare` and add `user_a` `user_b` to it

```
sudo groupadd datashare
sudo usermod -a datashare user_a
sudo usermod -a datashare user_b
```

2. We chage the own of `/path/to/usera/data` to `user_a`, group `datashare`

```
chown -R user_a:datashare /path/to/usera/data
```

3. add gooup permissions to read

```
chmod -R g+rx /path/to/usera/data
```

but `user_b` still not have permissions to access the dir

```
# user_b
cd /path/to/usera/data
-bash: cd: /path/to/usera/data: Permission denied

ls /path/to/usera/data
ls: cannot open directory '/path/to/usera/data': Permission denied
```

I am not sure what the step is worng?

We also tried `ACL`

```
setfacl -m u:user_b:rx /path/to/usera/data
```

its also not work

My question is whats wrong with this? and how to debug it if necessary, How to set linux permissions to share correctly?

Comment: Does `user_b` have `x` permissions (via groups or ACLs) to every component in `/path/to/usera/data` (i.e., all of `/`, `/path`, `/path/to`, `/path/to/usera`)?

Comment: In fact, no, what can I do if I cant allow `user_b` to access /path/to/usera/data parent directory?

Comment: Can you bind mount `/path/to/usera/data` somewhere that `user_b` can access? If not, you can't do anything

Comment: bind mount seems to require root permission, this seems to be a bit difficult, is there an alternative way that we can do this without breaking the original directory structure and copying files? Are hard links possible?

Comment: If you can hardlink every file in `/path/to/usera/data` recursively somewhere, sure, but either (a) you'd have to replicate the directory structure inside `data` in the new directory too, or (b) you'd have to flatten the structure in the new directory and handle collisions somehow; and on top of either one, make sure the directories stay in sync w.r.t. new files and directories.

Comment: If you add the bind mount to `/etc/fstab` and set `user` option, you don't need `sudo` to mount.

Comment: You could also try `bindfs`. https://www.idc-online.com/technical_references/pdfs/information_technology/Local_File_Sharing_in_Linux.pdf

Comment: @muru I tested this with a hardlink and it appears to be a workaround. @ pLumo It is possible to add settings to /etc/fstab, but we cannot currently afford to reboot, and I am uncertain if other methods like 'remount' with new parameters will cause program-aware disruptions to filesystem operations. It seems that there is no simple way to grant different users access to specific parts of a file within a large project with a specific structure. Thank you all for your suggestions

Comment: Bind mounts won't affect existing mounts, just use some path that's not used by anything else. You can use bind mounts with the `user` option as suggested by @pLumo without rebooting the system.